# CSS style color and more wont load

Tags: html, css

I'm having a bit of a problem with my CSS code in my website project. I was designing a html form but when i applied the changes in the stylesheet file, the new text colors did not want to be applied etc. And i also added a specific color to this `*` in the code below but it did not want to change the color either.

[image: Picture of the result]

```css
.apply {
    width: 320px;
    height: 420px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 70px 30px;
}

.apply input[type="text"], [type="text"], [type="email"]
{
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    background: transparent;
    outline: none;
    height: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
}

h1 .pageHeader {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 20;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #fff;
}

body {
    background-color: #24252A;
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

.required {
    color: rgb(255,99,71);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

text in your input will have given color only when this input have some value.
Without value there is displayed placeholder text which have his own styling.

look for [::placeholder pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder)

```css
input::placeholder {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Type here...">
```

Comment: oh okay, but that was not really the problem with this one. I encountered a problem with my css code when it comes to the text both outside and inside the form tag. The problem is that the color i've tried to place on `Applications format`, `Name` and `Email` was not getting placed. i tried a couple of methods but it still did not work to add white color to those text.

Comment: @Adde can you share snippet (html/css/js) that will show this issue?